# Accorder la construction « ce doit être »

Tags: accord, pluriel, conjugaison, constructions, concordance-des-temps

On conjugue volontiers « ce doit être » pour faire concorder les temps:

> Ce doit être un fantôme.
>   Ce devait être incroyable.

Doit-on l'accorder selon l'objet ?

> *Ce doivent être des maraudeurs.*
>   *Ce devaient être les vacances.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dans:

> ce doit être un fantôme

**doit être** est une forme impersonnelle du verbe devoir. Au pluriel, selon [Cordial](http://dictionnaire.cordial-enligne.fr/definition/devoir), l'accord est indifférent. On peut donc écrire aussi bien:

> ce doit être des fantômes

que:

> ce doivent être des fantômes

L'écriture de:

> ce devait être incroyable

est tout à fait acceptable. Pour le dernier exemple, l'écriture de

> ce **devait** être les vacances

est plus utilisée que "Ce devaient être les vacances" (Source google Ngram Viewer:"ce devaient être les,ce devait être les").

Comment: Comme du cristal. Merci :) Dommage que « ce doit être des » sonne encore faux à mes oreilles..

Comment: Pour ma part je ne serais pas aussi absolu. Bien que je comprenne la logique, je rappelle qu'on peut dire "ce sont les vacances" comme "c'est les vacances". Je trouve aussi des exemples de "ce pourraient être des...". Je pense qu'il y a plus à dire que "ça c'est bon, ça c'est faux".

Comment: ce de « ce doit être des fantômes» est une contraction de ceci (pronom demonstratif au singulier), c'est pourquoi "doit être" se met au singulier et ne s'accorde pas avec le pluriel "fantômes"

Comment: @Simon Déchamps Pour "ce sont les vacances", c'est tout à fait correct car il s'agit du verbe "être" et non du verbe "devoir" :)

Comment: Petite précision: Selon [Cordial](http://dictionnaire.cordial-enligne.fr/definition/devoir), on peut écrire "Ce doit être" ou "ce doivent être" devant un pluriel. L'accord est indifférent. "Ce doit être des gens très simples. Ce doivent être des gens très simples".

Comment: @SimonDéchamps En effet, la nuance est de mise, merci. La réponse de [sapienz](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/24825/7400) a été ajustée en conséquence :)

Answer (score 2):

Les deux sont possibles. Au présent, l'accord était plus courant avant 1960 et semble de nouveau reprendre le dessus.

Source: Grevisse - Le Bon Usage

> Le singulier est particulièrement fréquent dans certains cas : […] dans les expressions ce peut être, ce doit être. Mais le plur. est loin d’être rare : **Ce peuvent être** les jeux méchants d’un enchanteur (Bédier, Roman de Tristan et Iseut, cit. Høybye, § 96). — **Ce doivent être** deux Orientaux (Proust, Rech., t. II, p. 696). — **Ce doivent être** les journaux turcs […] qui les renseignent (Cocteau, Maalesh, p. 159).

NGram

[image]

Pour ce qui est de l'imparfait, le retour du pluriel qui était la forme préférée avant 1975 semble peut-être s'amorcer lui-aussi :

[image]

Comment: Curieusement, « ce doivent être » me paraît moins surprenant que « ce devaient être ».. est-il simplement plus fréquent ?

Comment: @iago-lito D'après NGram, "ce devraient être + pluriel" est deux ou trois fois plus fréquent que "ce doivent être" + pluriel, et il n'y a pas de différence majeure entre le singulier et le pluriel dans les deux temps.

Comment: Aha ? « ce devaient être » ou « ce dev**r**aient être » ? ^ ^ Je m'en vais visiter NGram.

Comment: Oui, j'avais mal lu. J'ajoute un graphique pour ce devaient être.

Comment: Vraiment intéressant. C'est l'usage qui fait la langue au fond, non ? Merci :)

Comment: Oui, et même « le bon usage » ;-)

Comment: Le mauvais usage aussi, tous les jours ;-)

Comment: @Frank Il n'y a pas de mauvais usages, il n'y a que de mauvais usagers... ;-)

Comment: Oui, bon ou mauvais, c'est l'Usage. Pour ce qui est des usagers, effectivement - et  ça râle souvent en plus ;-)